# There is log block not surrounded by if - PMD Violation

Tags: java, logging, pmd

```
package com;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class LoggerTest {
private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(LoggerTest.class);

public static void main(String arg[]) {

    if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
        logger.debug("debug");
    }

    if (logger.isInfoEnabled()) {
        logger.info("info");
    }
}
}
```

While running PMD violation - check code I am getting **There is log block not surrounded by if** violation. Colud you please any one tell me how to fix this violation.

This violation happens only for info level.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: not sure but try adding `{}` around `logger.info("info");` explicitly

Comment: @JigarJoshi - Thanks for reply. but even i am getting same violation.I tried before itself.

Comment: can you post exact error/warning message please

Comment: @JigarJoshi - The warning is "There is log block not surrounded by if"

Comment: are you sure this is the class and it is reflected changes with before supplying to pmd ?

Comment: This is test class i tried.

Comment: http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/pmd/pmd/4.2/rulesets/logging-java.xml i don't see that rule violated here

Answer (score 4):

This rule is not working correctly. In later versions it was disabled. The recent version of PMD (5.1.1) has a rule called [GuardLogStatementJavaUtil](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/pmd-5.1.1/rules/java/logging-java.html#GuardLogStatementJavaUtil), which does the same thing, but that one works.

UPDATE:

I've tried with the following code:

```
private static final Log log = LogFactoryImpl.getLog("apache.commons.logger");
private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("java.util.logger");

public static void main(String[] args) {
    if (log.isInfoEnabled()) {
        log.info("jebediah");
    }
    if (logger.isLoggable(Level.INFO)) {
        logger.info("kerman");
    }
}
```

After running PMD I got two warning messages:

1) At the line `log.info("jebediah");` I get the following error message: ***Java Logging -> GuardLogStatementJavaUtil***

2) At the line `logger.info("kerman");` I get the following error message: ***Jakarta Commons Logging -> GuardLogStatement***

Looks like whatever I do, I'll get a warning.

Comment: I am getting same violation for info level while using the isLoggable method .    if(log.isLoggable(java.util.logging.Level.INFO)){
   log.info("done");
  }

Comment: I updated my answer. I guess PMD fails to recognize which logger am I using so it will fire a warning anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Changed info log to debug and it started to pass.

Comment: This solution not worked for  me

Answer (score 1):

You can add

```
@SuppressWarnings("PMD.GuardLogStatementJavaUtil")
```

on your method to disable this warning.

Example usage:

```
@SuppressWarnings("PMD.GuardLogStatementJavaUtil")
private void sample() {
  if (logger.isInfoEnabled()) {
    logger.info("sample log");
  }
}
```

Comment: This worked for me by just adding the if statement